# Implement sizeof operator using bitwise operation

Tags: sizeof

During an interview for the position of C/C++ , I faced one question  Write a c program to implement `sizeof` operator ,I have wrote the code ,Then he asked me to implement using bitwise operations .I tried for int.... But I coudlnt ,,,, anyone can post the code ,, how to implement ,,,

Comment: What language and how the heck would you even do that? What kind of interview was this?

Comment: That's wrong and it only works for a specific set of types. And a very small set, since it's a finite one, and the set of all possible types is not finite. The question is stupid to start with. Do not take the job.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this, since the set of data types that support bitwise operations is not a superset of the set of types that support `sizeof`.

Proof: `int*`.